# How to trigger an window service by an click of button which is in MVC framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an Windows service and an Asp.net MVC framework project in which I need to trigger/Start this Windows service. So how should, I must trigger/Start an windows service on click button of Asp.net MVC Project?

Comment: Can you please [edit] to clarify: What is "Window service"- It is possible you mean "Windows service"? As "MVC framework" you mean "asp.net mvc"? If you talking about Windows service and asp.net MVC - are both running on the same server?

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger a windows service"?

Comment: @KlausGütter i mean to start windows service from Asp.net Mvc

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  i am running them both separately on my local system. the flow of Asp.net MVC project goes like this, i have build and Asp.net application where i can upload an file which can be in csv or etc file and also  i have made an validation button. Then i use this Windows Service to check if data is valid or not, for now i'm doing it manually by going in run->service.msc and start the window service. But i want to start this window service by click of validation button in asp.net  mvc application.

Comment: While it sounds like a bad idea I'm sure it was asked before... Could you please [edit] the question to clarify what your research https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+start+service+aspnet showed and why none of the existing solutions worked for you or what exact part of the operation you could not find any information about?